# CSS Files in ASP.NET MVC with a master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, master-pages

I'm designing an MVC site, and I've already got quite a few things in the `Site.css` that only apply to one controller or even one page.  I'd like to break this out into multiple css files and include them only when necessary, but how can I do this when all header information is in the `Site.Master`.

**Note:** I still want to use master pages, I just want some header resources to be per page or per controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding a ContentPlaceHolder into my Site.master header and then linking to the CSS statements via that placeholder.  It works well from what I've seen.

Example:

```
<head runat="server">
  <title>Site Master</title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="css" runat="server" />
  <link href="~/css/css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Something else to consider - if you have a lot of "one-off" CSS styles, you may want to [think about how you're setting up the styles in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253110/how-to-manage-css-explosion).

Comment: I think that's the common technique. You can link javascripts and set titles (or add any other HEAD declarations) for each page specifically this way.