# Organize class in CSS file

Tags: css

During development a lot of times I need to apply just a small enhancement to an html tag.
For example : a red border ,or a float left.

The best practice dictate to keep all the code in one/several css files,avoid inline styling 
and keep ids to a minimum.

So how do I keep organize the css file with so many small groups of properties and how do I remember if I have one already or not. Should I just build a lot of small css classes ? How does this concept apply in a team ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Manage CSS Explosion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253110/how-to-manage-css-explosion)

Answer (score 0):

I have found comments to work best for my use.  I usually break up my CSS document by page or display item such as

`/* Contact Form */`

or

`/* About Us Table */`

It really comes down to personal preference and coming to an agreement with your other team members on how to document your project.