# how to achieve such a scrolling div with changing css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This [site](http://www.builtbymoby.com/) has a scrolling div on the left. As you scroll the page the div also scrolls rhythmically and the color of the image also gets changed. `position:fixed` is not all that can do it .

What is the technique then ?

**EDIT:**

`position:fixed` is all that I can use to get a div fixed at a location with the page scrolling. But how to add the rhythm of the changing div?  What else research effort do I need to show (negative ranking)?

Comment: Did you try looking at the source code? http://www.builtbymoby.com/scripts/home.js

Comment: yes I did. Already a negative point... Any help to understand the code? or any other easy way?

Comment: I'm guessing that you got dinged because the code is right there and pretty easy to follow.

Comment: I would also add, that they don't use `position: fixed` but relatively positioned elements within in absolute positioned container. You should be aware, that a fixed position can cause you a lot of trouble on mobile devices like iOS. Also if you want to achieve a scrolling effect (the divs moves slightly slower than the real content), this won't work on iOS. As it will slide in **after** the scrolling has come to an end.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, what should be done for perfection?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using jquery.

```
var divs = $('.fademe');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > 50 && st < 100) {
        $('.fademe').css({
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.fademe').css({
            'color': '#000'
        });
    }    
});
```

this function will change the color of the text in a div when the scroll bar position is between 50 and 100. otherwise the text will be black

you can modify the jquery code above to alter any css you'd like.

try it yourself here http://jsfiddle.net/J8XaX/29/

added bounce with this one http://jsfiddle.net/J8XaX/43/

Hope this helps

Comment: what is about the rhythm the div moves with?

Comment: that is a css property i'm guessing. instead of using position:fixed you could use the same jquery above to modify the css `top` property.

Comment: if I add top property, will that add the bounce-like effect ?

Comment: Most likely not, I thought you question was how to change the css of the div like the colors being changed from the site in your question. not the effect of having a div that moves with the scroll bar as there are many many tutorials on how it can be accomplished

Comment: can you provide any link please ?

Comment: hey I added a second JsFiddle with a bounce effect. Check me answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: please notice that the bounce the site has gets the div to appear from an invisible state to a fixed position. How to achieve that ? I used your code in localhost and found in console that bounce() is undefined though the same effect as in jsfiddle is visible.

Comment: I apologize I'm not able to give you exactly the same effect as that website. however I've given you the tools to do so. I wish you good luck with your programming.